# Restrict access to a section of the site implemented by a custom module

Tags: 7, users

I have a site with two different type of users: clients and anonymous users.

I'm currently building custom modules to handle a "client administration" section of the site, where clients are able to change their profiles, modify custom settings, etc. There is a section of the site "client" users are able to access, but regular users are not.

How can I restrict access to that section to only a particular class of user?

Answer (score 5):

If you implement [hook_permission](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) in your custom module, you can control the access of your client administration section.

1. Set up roles. You've done this already with the client role.
2. Implement hook_permission():

   ```
   function MODULE_permission()
   {
       return array(
           'access client administration' => array(
               'title'       => t('Access Client Administration'),
               'description' => t('Allow users to access client administration'),
           ),
       );
   }
   ```
3. When you define hook_menu(), make sure you set the permissions accordingly:

   ```
   function MODULE_menu()
   {
       $items['client_administration'] = array(
           'title' => 'Client Administration Page',
   ...
           'access arguments' => array('access client administration'),
       );

       return $items;
   }
   ```
4. Go to admin/people/permissions and set the permissions for 'Access Client Administration' to your client role.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`hook_permission()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) in your custom module to define a new permission (e.g. "use module foo") and then assign that permission to the appropriate roles. Then check permissions with [`user_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7) wherever necessary in your module.